# modal stuck with first iteration in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, html5-canvas

I am trying to generate modal every iteration in ngFor.  it's like the data that i passed to the modal did not change with the iteration of ngFor (stuck in the first iteration). I don't know what to do.
Here is my html code.

```
<div class="container">
    <div *ngFor="let note of allNotes.slice().reverse()">
        <div class="card">
            <div style="padding: 20px;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="../../assets/angular.png">
            </div>

            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{note.title}}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{note.content | summary:300 }}</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" (click)="openModal(note)">Show Details</button>
                <!-- Modal Starts -->
                <div class="modal" role="dialog" [ngStyle]="{'display':display}">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">{{ note.title }}</h4>
                                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="onCloseHandled()"><span
                                        aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                {{ note.content }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="onCloseHandled()">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Delete Note</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Modal Ends -->
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                {{ note.time | timeAgo }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my .ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import notes from '../notes.data';

@Component({
  selector: 'show-notes',
  templateUrl: './show-notes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./show-notes.component.css']
})
export class ShowNotesComponent implements OnInit {
  allNotes = notes;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  display = "none";

  openModal() {
    this.display = "block";
  }
  onCloseHandled() {
    this.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Could you please help me out of it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `allNotes` look like in your component?

Comment: Could you please add the TS part ?

Comment: `interface note {
    id: number,
    time: number,
    title: string,
    content: string
};

Answer (score 1):

For `slice()` you must give the start and end values, I assume that due to its absence it only takes one. If you're only interested on reverse them, remove the `slice()` call.

Comment: This is probably done to clone the array since `reverse` mutates.